# start fragment from another class android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a class called SMSRecevier that receives and interprets messages and depending on the message certain tasks have to be made.
I have a RegisterPhoneActivity and a RegisterPhoneFragment that I want to attach to that activity when a certain SMS arrives. How can I do that?
I tried this: 
in SMSReceiver:

```
if (messageBody.contains(context.getResources().getString(R.string.numberResponse)))
                {
                    String[] parts = messageBody.split(" ");
                    String number1 = parts[3];
                    String number2 = parts[5];
                    String number3 = parts[7];
                    RegisterPhoneActivity registerPhoneActivity=new RegisterPhoneActivity();
                    registerPhoneActivity.showNumberFragment(number1, number2, number3);
                }
```

in RegisterPhoneActivity:

```
public void showNumberFragment(String no1, String no2, String no3)
{
    View container=findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (container!= null) {

        RegisterPhoneFragment newFragment = new RegisterPhoneFragment();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putString(RegisterPhoneFragment.NUMBER1, no1);
     args.putString(RegisterPhoneFragment.NUMBER2, no2);
     args.putString(RegisterPhoneFragment.NUMBER3, no3);
     newFragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: is RegisterPhoeActivity extend FragmentActvity?

Comment: By doing so, I get container null. I guess this happens because i create a new instance of RegisterPhoneActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface and use a callback to let the activity know that an SMS has been received.

```
public interface OnSmsReceivedListener {
    void onSMSReceived(int arg1, string arg2); ..<----add arguments you want to pass back
}
```

In your SMS receiver class

```
ArrayList<OnSmsReceivedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnSmsReceivedListener>();

...

public void addSmsReceivedListener(OnSmsReceivedListener listener){
    if (!listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeSmsReceivedListener(OnSmsReceivedListener listener){
    if (listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

When you receive an SMS that matches your criteria:

```
for (OnSmsReceivedListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onSMSReceived(arg1, arg2);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class RegisterPhoneActivity extends Activity implements OnSmsReceivedListener {

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...
    smsRecevier.addResponseReceivedistener(this); <--- this is the instance of your receiver
    ...
}

public void onSMSReceived(int arg1, string arg2){
   // do whatever you need to do
}


@Override
public void onPause(){

    ...
    smsReceiver.removeSmsReceivedListener(this);
    ...

}
```

All from memory so please excuse typos.

This approach decouples the classes.  The SMS receiver has no knowledge of the activities.  It simply calls back to any listeners registered.

Those listeners might be Activities, they might be services.  They might be instances of `MySparklyUnicorn`.  The receiver neither knows nor cares.  It simply says "if anyone's interested, I've received an SMS and here are the details".

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW, you should never use `new` to create an Activity.  Only ever use `Intent`.

Comment: I have public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver. This somehow exists independently. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android
Followed this tutorial. How can i add listeners to that object? I should not create a new instance of recevier in every activity but use the global one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) parameter in any class(here you need that in your `SMSRecevier` class) you can start any activity with `startActivity` method of context.